# No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\org1\wp-settings.php

Tags: php, wordpress

After installing a theme I get this error:

> **Warning**: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\org1/wp-includes/post.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\org1\wp-settings.php** on line **166**
>
> **Fatal error**: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\org1/wp-includes/post.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in **C:\xampp\htdocs\org1\wp-settings.php** on line **166**

I can't access any page (at least dashboard), how to fix it?

Comment: Just use default wp and use that theme, is that still causing the issue?

Comment: I just copy and pasted post.php from another installation and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

> You can reinstall the wordpress and then try to activate the theme. Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I tried several times but it happening again and again

Comment: happend with only with this theme or the other themes too ?

Comment: I tried two themes the same thing happened with both